# Get a response value out of an IResult in ASP.Net's minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I'm porting a project to the new **minimal api** of ASP.Net 6.

Right now I have something similar to this:

```
builder.MapGet("/hello", CiaoCiao);

IResult CiaoCiao()
{
    return Results.Ok("Ciao ciao!");
}
```

The reason for having the endpoint implementation in a separate function is that I want to write a unit test for it. But I'm having the following issue:

How do I get the response value (in this case the string `"Ciao ciao!"`) out of the `IResult`?

So far I didn't find anything in the official documentation about that. There is a class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Result.OkObjectResult` which I could cast to. But that's internal to `AspNetCore`, so it's not accessible from my unit test project.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible with ASP.NET Core 6 as all the implementations of `IResult` are internal.

This is [planned to be improved](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37502) as part of ASP.NET Core 7.

Integration testing your code via the HTTP interface would be one way of testing your application's endpoints with ASP.NET Core 6 using the `WebApplicationFactory<T>` class ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)).

Comment: Thanks. There is a workaround I can use in the github issue. It will do for now. I'm aware of WebApplicationFactory, but that would require to set up authorization. A bit too cumbersome for a unit test.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to come up with a workaround using some code in the [github issue linked by Martin Costello](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37502) in his answer:

```
private static async Task<T?> GetResponseValue<T>(IResult result)
{
    var mockHttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        // RequestServices needs to be set so the IResult implementation can log.
        RequestServices = new ServiceCollection().AddLogging().BuildServiceProvider(),
        Response =
        {
            // The default response body is Stream.Null which throws away anything that is written to it.
            Body = new MemoryStream(),
        },
    };

    await result.ExecuteAsync(mockHttpContext);

    // Reset MemoryStream to start so we can read the response.
    mockHttpContext.Response.Body.Position = 0;
    var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
    return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(mockHttpContext.Response.Body, jsonOptions);
}
```

Ugly, but seems to work.

Comment: Isnt be easier and much more readable and mantainable  just to create a controller action?

Comment: @Serge not sure I understand your comment. What do you mean? You don't have controllers with the minimal API.

Comment: No, you don' t have, But the pourpose of minimal Api is  one line code. If it is more than one line then it is easier to create a controller, then to use your hundred lines code. Min api makes sense only if you have one line of very simple code.

Comment: I disagree. Minimal API you can have more complicated APIs its simply removing a lot of the scaffolding and simplifying it. See this post from Nick Chapas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ORO-KOufeU the code examples by Microsoft are really poor.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to do something simple like :

```
        [Fact]
        public void Then_it_returns_bad_request_result() =>
            _result.ToString().Should().EndWith("BadRequestObjectResult");
```

Not particularly satisfying, but does the job until I can investigate a better alternative using .NET7.